# Simulate a swipe momevent in As3, Flash or Flex

Tags: actionscript-3, events, button, touch, swipe

Here's my dilemma:

If I add buttons to a Sprite, I have to listen for the MOUSE_DOWN or CLICK event to make the button work as it should.

However, I want the sprite that contains the button to function like a touchscreen device, and I want the contents of the sprite to scroll up-and-down when you swipe it...

I am afraid the mouse events of the buttons will prevent the events from being captured by the container. This would mean that when I swipe over the button, the button get's clicked instead of the container.

I know Flex passes events down the chain of elements, but I don't believe this is the case for Flash.. ?

Comment: Have you tried using MOUSE_UP instead of MOUSE_DOWN so it does not throw the event by directly clicking. Otherwise you can try to use preventDefault() in your handler.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `MOUSE_UP` event instead of `MOUSE_DOWN`, it's better practice, even if not to consider problems with scrolling. After there's nothing on `MOUSE_UP` you can hang

```
function onMouseDown(e: Event) {
  flag = true
}
```

on `MOUSE_DOWN`. After that

```
function onMouseDown(e: Event) {
  if (flag) {
    //scrolling here
  }
}
```

and dont forget to set `flag=fasle` on `MOUSE_UP`.